# Ineligible Submission:how to enhance the rating and user engagement?

Tags: facebook-app-center

What features would have my canvas app to submit application on App Center?
Facebook give me this response:

Ineligible Submission
Your app does not have high enough ratings and user engagement to be eligible for the App Center at this time.

What could I do to enhance my rating and user engagement?

Answer (score 0):

I agree, its not a very helpfull message from facebook, how to get high ratings how much user engagement, they don't tell you this information before you start to write an app!

Comment: Please start a bounty for this. I am so much in need of this answer

Comment: Why develop an API and then not tell anyone this important information. Are the API's only for the established giants with plenty of money to spend on marketing? When you view the game apps page on a tablet there doesn't seem to be a search bar only a list of most popular apps in order of popularity, oh yes there is also a set of sections, but no searchable tags, but without a app page your app is invisible regardless of its quality. I would like to know how are smaller developers supposed to get in on the action, I am now regretting my time spent on learning the FB API?

Answer (score 0):

Some advice from a facebook guy, not me ...

There are no numbers because it is not as simple as you need more than 1000 users and a rating higher than 4. We weigh both user engagement and ratings together with other stuff to try to figure out what a high quality app is.

There are several other ways your can get visibility. Publish Open Graph stories and using Requests are 2 things you can do.

Comment: Is this 1000 views and +4 rating in the iTunes app store? Or somewhere else?

Comment: this is within facebook, apparently they randomly ask people to rank apps